# Having Problem With Checked ComboBox Text

Tags: c#, winforms

I issued a problem with a checked combobox code which I downloaded from this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31105/A-ComboBox-with-a-CheckedListBox-as-a-Dropdown?fid=1530839&df=90&mpp=25&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&prof=True&view=Normal&fr=1#xx0xx).

I want to have my combobox text changes when I'm checking the checkboxes but it has some kind of delay.

I think the issue lies in the `ItemCheckEventHandler`, if so what should I do to resolve it?

I've tried replacing :

```
private void cclb_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    if (ccbParent.ItemCheck != null) {
        ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e);
        ccbParent.Text = GetCheckedItemsStringValue();
    }
}
```

with :

```
private void cclb_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e){
    List<string> checkedItems = new List<string>();
    foreach (var item in cclb.CheckedItems) {
        checkedItems.Add(item.ToString());
    }

    if (e.NewValue == CheckState.Checked) {
        checkedItems.Add(cclb.Items[e.Index].ToString());
    }
    else {
        checkedItems.Remove(cclb.Items[e.Index].ToString());
    }
    foreach (string item in checkedItems) {
        ccbParent.ItemCheck(sender, e);
        ccbParent.Text = GetCheckedItemsStringValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please can you format your code. It would benefit from proper indentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need all this code in your cclb_ItemCheck event. You have delay now because every time you check something you have two foreach loops that are totally unnecessary.

If I understood your question correctly your cclb_ItemCheck should look something like this:

```
private void ccb_ItemCheck(object sender, ItemCheckEventArgs e) {
    CCBoxItem item = ccbParent.Items[e.Index] as CCBoxItem;
    ccbParent.Text += item.Name.toString() + ", ";
}
```

Or something like that... I suggest you make a new project and follow the example from the link of the blog post that you provided.

Comment: thanks fot that,theres one more question to ask : what should i use for "CCBoxItem" ???

Comment: I saw a small mistake so I edited my answer, I renamed ccb into ccbParent in the first line of the method. Hope that makes sense now. CCBoxItem is going to be checkbox item that triggered the ItemCheck event.